# unable to alert id of checked checkboxes correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

php&html

```
<?php
 $param=$_GET['param'];
 $sql= "SELECT * FROM categories,main_category WHERE categories.main_cat_id=main_category.main_cat_id AND categories.main_cat_id='$param'";
 $stmt = $pdo->query($sql); 
?>

              <table class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 medium-centered large-centered columns pop_tbl"><tr>
              <?php
              $i=0;
              while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
              {
                  $i++;
                  //echo $i;

              ?>
             <td>
             <label for="level_<?php echo $row['catid'];?>">
              <input type="checkbox" class="level" id="level_<?php echo $row['catid'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['catid'];?>" onchange="searchcourse('<?php echo $row['catid'];?>')">
             <span></span>
              <?php echo $row['catname'];?>

              </label>
             </td>

              <?php
              if($i==2)
                  {
                      echo"</tr><tr>";
                      $i=0;
                  }
              }
              ?>
        </tr></table>
```

script

```
function searchcourse(param)
{$("input[type=checkbox][id^=level]").change(function() {  

  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
  } else {
   alert("not checked");
  }


});
}
```

The scenario is, when the checkbox is checked a call to the searchcourse function made. I expect this function recognize if the checkbox is clicked or not and after that alert the id of the checked checkbox. But what it does is,
when the first checkbox in the array is checked, it alerts nothing!

WHen I uncheck it, it alerts 'not checked'. Then for the second checkbox in the array, it straight away says checked when checked and 'not checked' when unchecked.

Apart from this issue, the alert suppose to appear once per event change. But it remembers how many times the checkboxes are clicked and that mnay times pops up. for instance, the first checkbox first checked but shown nothing. SO I uncheked it,(2 times altready). The alert now shown twice. WHen I check and uncheck the second checkbox (now 4 times already). SO the alerts appear 4 times!

Why is it so? SOmeone please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You've bound the event twice, first you do this

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="searchcourse()" />
```

And then you do

```
function searchcourse(param) {

    $("input[type=checkbox][id^=level]").change(function() {  

        // stuff

    });
}
```

So everytime the change event fires, the `searchcourse` function fires, and binds a new event handler, and it keeps multplying, 2 times, 4 times, 8 times etc.

Just remove the `onclick` handler in the HTML and the function all together, an keep the jQuery event handler only

Comment: at first I just used jquery event handler but it doesn't alert anything thats why I used onclick.

Comment: Then you've placed the jQuery script in the wrong place, or not wrapped it in document ready.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is wrong because you call it in the onchange event and this function also use the event change, so you are having this issue about having a lot of popups.

What I recommend to use is using the onclick event and call your function but just with your if code like this

```
function searchcourse(check,param){
 if($(check).is(":checked"))  alert($(check).attr("id"));
 else alert("not checked");
}
```

I hope It helps

Regards

Comment: I tried your code, but it  alerts 'not checked' no matter i check or uncheck

Comment: Sorry man, You have to send also 'this' on the onclick like this onclick="searchcourse(this, '<?php echo $row['catid'];?>')"

Comment: Above I change the function